# Is it possible to read a local Excel 97-2003 file (.xls) in a Flash application?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, excel

All,

I'm exploring the feasibility of reading data from a local Excel file in a Flash application.

Thanks to Ben Morrow's ***awesome*** *XLSX READER* (https://github.com/childoftv/as3-xlsx-reader), it's possible to read Excel 2007 files.

It works ***beautifully***.

However, that function doesn't read Excel 97-2003 files.

I found this:

http://code.google.com/p/as3xls/

Which should read Excel files in Flex, but I'm working on a Flash application, and it looks like as3xls relies on a number of Flex only functions and types (ArrayCollection, NumberFormatter, etc.)

Since I'm not familiar with Flex, I'm having a difficult time making the adjustments myself.

Has anyone built a Flash app that reads Excel 97-2003 files, and is willing to share tips or code?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Take the leap and learn a new language. I can't hurt you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One avenue you can explore is to wrap the Flex classes into a swc that you can use in Flash. The basic idea can be found here: http://flashauthoring.blogspot.com/2009/02/using-class-stringutil-in-flash.html

I have not tried it yet myself but it seems possible.